# mysql cannot import csv lines terminated with \r\n\r\n using load data local

Tags: mysql, csv, load-data-infile, eol

I am trying to import the [CSV provided by a service that should give me cities database](https://www.geodatasource.com/world-cities-database/free).

The way format of the cities in csv format is:

```
CC_FIPS FULL_NAME_ND
AN  Aixas

AN  Aixirivall

AN  Aixovall

AN  Andorra la Vella

AN  Ansalonga
```

So I came up with the following mysql query:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL
INFILE 'GEODATASOURCE-CITIES-FREE.TXT'
INTO TABLE `city`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(cc_fips,full_name_nd);
```

They all get imported but the entries under the column of `full_name_nd` has a whitespace after. Since as you can see there's extra `\r\n` at the end of each line.

Which I can confirm with `cat short.txt | od -c`

```
0000000   C   C   _   F   I   P   S  \t   F   U   L   L   _   N   A   M
0000020   E   _   N   D  \r  \n   A   N  \t   A   i   x   a   s  \r  \n
0000040  \r  \n   A   N  \t   A   i   x   i   r   i   v   a   l   l  \r
0000060  \n  \r  \n   A   N  \t   A   i   x   o   v   a   l   l  \r  \n
0000100  \r  \n   A   N  \t   A   n   d   o   r   r   a       l   a
0000120   V   e   l   l   a  \r  \n  \r  \n   A   N  \t   A   n   s   a
0000140   l   o   n   g   a  \r  \n  \r  \n   A   N  \t   A   n   y   o
0000160   s  \r  \n  \r  \n   A   N  \t   A   r   a   n   s  \r  \n  \r
0000200  \n   A   N  \t   A   r   i   n   s   a   l  \r  \n  \r  \n   A
0000220   N  \t   A   u   b   i   n   y   a  \r  \n  \r  \n   A   N  \t
```

So modifying the query, using `\r\n\r\n`:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL
INFILE 'GEODATASOURCE-CITIES-FREE.TXT'
INTO TABLE `city`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(cc_fips,full_name_nd);
```

But that query won't work :(

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.40 sec)
Records: 0  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
```

I even tried with

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL
INFILE 'GEODATASOURCE-CITIES-FREE.TXT'
INTO TABLE `city`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(cc_fips,@col_with_spaces)
SET full_name_nd = TRIM(@col_with_spaces);
```

But apparently, `TRIM()` doesn't work on `\r`, `\n` or other special whitespaces.

Hope somebody can help.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED.** using `dos2unix` tool on the `'GEODATASOURCE-CITIES-FREE.TXT'` first before using the SQL query I posted in my question solved it. Looking forward to anyone who can explain why converting it to `unix` line endings solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work as I haven't tested it, but have you tried replacing the special characters. Something like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL
INFILE 'GEODATASOURCE-CITIES-FREE.TXT'
INTO TABLE `city`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(cc_fips,@col_with_spaces)
SET full_name_nd = TRIM(REPLACE(@col_with_spaces, '\r\n', ''));
```

If it doesn't work, try to use '\n' instead of '\r\n'.

Comment: Thanks for checking.

Comment: @TheWolf, text files created on DOS/Windows machines have different line endings than files created on Unix/Linux. The file you got from GeoDataSource was probably generated in a DOS environment with "\r\n". Therefore, running dos2unix on it resolved the line endings issue. You can also do it the other way with unix2dos.